# Is Ashley Stubbs a host on Westworld?

Tags: westworld-tv

When Stubbs stopped the Dolores-as-Charlotte host on her way to the boat to the mainland, he says Ford hired him "so many years ago I can hardly remember it". This sounds an awful lot like Bernard, back in Season 1, before anyone knew he was a host. He also says "he (Ford) was very clear about my role here, who I was supposed to be loyal to. Guess you could call **it my core drive**." Is he really a host?

Comment: Season 3 episode 2 reveals that he is a host

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Westworld season 3 episode 2 reveals that Ashly Stubbs was actually a host

Answer (score 10):

This is was **co-creator Lisa Joy** **[had to say about it](https://www.thewrap.com/westworld-season-2-finale-questions-dolores-bernard-hale-lisa-joy/)**:

> **When Halores left the beach, it seemed like Stubbs knew it was Dolores
>   — or at least that it wasn’t Hale. Is that safe to assume?**
>
> > Yes! It is safe to assume. And there is a step further that you
> >     can assume too. And **we don’t say it explicitly, but if you are left
> >     wondering with all [Stubbs’] talk**, his knowing talk about, “I’ve been
> >     at the park a very long time,” and Ford designed him with certain core
> >     drives, and he’s gonna stick to the role he’s been programmed with;
> >     **it’s a little acknowledgement of just why he might have his suspicions
> >     about what’s going on with Hale, and then lets her pass**.
> >
> > And **doesn’t it make sense if you are Ford and designing a park and you
> >     have a whole master plan about helping robots that you would keep one
> >     Host hiding in plain sight as a fail-safe?** Maybe the Host who’s in
> >     charge of quality assurance? And by the way, that was totally meant to
> >     be subtle [laughs].

**Fred Toye**, the director of the episode **[also confirmed](https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2018/06/westworld-finale-is-stubbs-a-host-robot)** that, as far as he knows, **Stubbs is a host** (and the scene was re-written by co-creator Jonah Nolan the night before it was shot)